# How to make parsleyjs only trigger validation on blur (for a field that has already failed validation)

Tags: parsley.js

I'm trying to figure out how to make parsleyjs only trigger validation on blur for a field that has **already** failed validation.

See http://jsfiddle.net/billyroebuck/zbmv2d3w/

Markup:

```
<form id="myform">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email"
        data-parsley-required="true"
        data-parsley-type="email"
        data-parsley-custom
        data-parsley-trigger="blur"
    />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('custom',
function (value, requirement) {
    console.log('custom validation triggered');
    sleepFor(3000); // simulate a delay (testing only)
    if (value == 'test@test.com') {
        console.log('custom validation failed');
        return false;
    }
    console.log('custom validation passed');
    return true;
}, 32)
    .addMessage('en', 'custom', 'custom validation failed');

$('#myform').parsley();

function sleepFor(sleepDuration) {
    console.log('pretend this takes a while...');
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < now + sleepDuration) { /* do nothing */
    }
}
```

parsleyjs Version 2.2.0-rc1

The email field has validation rules to check:

- a value is provided,
- the value entered is a valid email address,
- some custom rule (pretend this is an AJAX request)

I have the parsley-trigger attribute for this field set to blur.

Steps:

- Open the console
- Enter "a@b.com" in the email field above and press tab
- Note the custom validation is triggered (good)
- Enter "xyz" in the email field and press tab
- Note the parsley type validation kicks in (good)
- Enter "xyz@test.com" in the email field View the console
- Note the custom validation is triggered the moment the input becomes a
  valid email (in this case when you press the letter c in .com) vs
  blur :(

How can I make sure the validation is only triggered on the blur event for invalid fields?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no such option currently. The idea is to remove the error message as soon as possible and everyone appears to like this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I guess I can run the validation logic manually with my own blur event. Is there a way to add a custom message to a field without a parsley validator?

Comment: I noticed that even without the custom validator if you type really fast sometimes some of the characters are skipped (eg in firefox).